# How to know which row has been selected in a TableViewer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm using Viewer Framework in my Eclipse RCP Application, i was stuck at a situation wherein i need to get(know which row has been selected in the UI) the selected row from a TableViewer.
In UI user can be able to select a row.Below is my Tableviewer declaration

```
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION
    | SWT.HIDE_SELECTION);
```

i'm able to select a row in the sense when a user clicks on a particular row it gets highlighted, i wanted to know if which row has been selected by the user and fetch exactly the row details? How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In JFace you can add a selectionListener to your TableViewer. Instead of the selected row you'll get notified about the selected object. Heres the code:

```
this.viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: straight forward and apt answer gratitude